# Multidimensional array by user input in python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I used Jupyter notebook, I am new to Python, I try to fetch value from user in multidimensional array how I do that? I write a little code, after put first value I get error that I don't understand

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>    <ipython-input-64-4d8986a5e412> in <module>
>           5 for i in range(lengthrow):
>           6     for j in range(lengthcol):
>     ----> 7         arr[i][j]=int(input("enter value"))
>           8 print(arr)
> ```
>
> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

code:

```
from numpy import*
arr = array([[],[]])
lengthrow=int(input("enter array row length"))
lengthcol=int(input("enter array col length"))
for i in range(lengthrow):
    for j in range(lengthcol):
        arr[i][j]=int(input("enter value"))
print(arr)
```

Comment: You made `arr` a (2,0) shape array.  `arr[0]` is a (0,) shape array.  Trying to index that with [0] produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @Austin great answer and made some little changes:

```
import numpy as np

n_rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
n_cols = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))

arr = [[int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, c + 1))) for c in range(n_cols)] for r in range(n_rows)]

print(np.array(arr))
```

The output is:

```
Enter number of rows: 2
Enter number of columns: 3
Enter value for 1. row and 1. column: 1
Enter value for 1. row and 2. column: 2
Enter value for 1. row and 3. column: 3
Enter value for 2. row and 1. column: 4
Enter value for 2. row and 2. column: 5
Enter value for 2. row and 3. column: 6
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

You got an exception, because you initialized an empty array and used invalid indices. With this answer you generate the array after you have entered the users input.

---

Here is the long version of the one-liner (`arr = [[...`) which gives you the same result:

```
outer_arr = []
for r in range(n_rows):
    inner_arr = []
    for c in range(n_cols):
        num = int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, c + 1)))
        inner_arr.append(num)
    outer_arr.append(inner_arr)

print(np.array(outer_arr))
```

Comment: Thanks Darius Morawec, this method as also great actually I need this output thanks a lot.Can you suggest some reference to learn two dimensional array I need to deeply learn about it.Thank you :)

Comment: Sure, multidimensional arrays are matrices in linear algebra, which allows you do to powerful operations. Here are some introductions: [#1](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-scipy-tutorial), [#2](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_numpy_matrix_tutorial.php), [#3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_linear_algebra.htm) and [#4](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html).

Comment: Again Thanks a lot @Darius Morawiec :)

Comment: Can you explain this line [[int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, c + 1))) for c in range(n_cols)] for r in range(n_rows)]  i don't really understand how flow of for loop

Comment: @ToufikKhan Sure, I edited the answer and added a longer version of the same code. We use two for loops to create a list of lists which we convert to a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list-comprehension here as the final result is a list of lists:

```
lengthrow = int(input("enter array row length: "))
lengthcol = int(input("enter array col length: "))

arr = [[int(input("enter value: ")) for _ in range(lengthcol)] for _ in range(lengthrow)]

print(arr)
```

**Problem** with your code:

```
arr = array([[],[]])
print(arr.shape)
# (2, 0)
```

That means you have a size 0 column in array, so when you do `arr[0][0]`, for example, it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the shape of the initial array:

```
In [1]: arr = np.array([[], []])
In [2]: arr
Out[2]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
In [3]: arr[0]
Out[3]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [4]: arr[0][0]
... 
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Think of this array as 2 rows, 0 columns.  You can't reference a non-existent column.  And, in contrast to some other languages, you can't grow an array simply by referencing a new index.  Once created the size is fixed.

While others have shown nice list comprehension approaches, I'll show how to use your approach correctly:

```
In [8]: lengthrow, lengthcol = 2,3    # or user input
In [9]: arr = np.zeros((lengthrow, lengthcol), dtype=int)  # large enough array
In [10]: arr
Out[10]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
In [11]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     for j in range(3):
    ...:         arr[i,j] = int(input(f'{i},{j}:'))
    ...:         
0,0:0
0,1:1
0,2:2
1,0:3
1,1:4
1,2:5
In [12]: arr
Out[12]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable replay, this salutation is really good. once again thank you :)

Comment: np.array() function convert the list to numpy array