# flow of for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I just new in python, I code for fetch array value from user, for this reason I asked a question yesterday in stackoverflow. Darius Morawiec and Austin give me the best salutation, but I don't understand the flow of for loop, I google it, but I don't understand those explanation.can any body explain the control of "for" loop for given code below. Thank you

```
arr = [[int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, c + 1))) 
       for c in range(n_cols)] 
       for r in range(n_rows)]
```

[yesterday conversation Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654006/multidimensional-array-by-user-input-in-python)

Comment: You could've just asked for this clarification on the answer you got the code from.

Comment: I already asked him through comment, but I need the explanation as soon as possible

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python list comprehension", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: thank you @prune I must check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension is a compressed syntax in python to generate a list. If you rewrite this, it will probably be very clear.

The general syntax is: `[expression for element in list (optional: if condition)]` and it returns a list

This is exactly the same as writing:

```
new_list = []
for element in original_list:
    if (condition):   
        new_list.append(expression)
```

in your case, you can rewrite the two list comprehensions (they are nested) like so:

arr = `[[second comprehension] for r in range(n_rows)]` ->

```
arr = []
for r in range(n_rows):
    arr.append(second list)
```

now, for the second list comprehension:

```
second_list = []
for c in range(n_cols):
    entry = int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, c + 1)))
    second_list.append(entry)
```

And the entire flow is:

```
arr = []
for r in range(n_rows):
    second_list = []
    for c in range(n_cols):
            entry = int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, c + 1)))
            second_list.append(entry)
    arr.append(second list)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tacratis i got my best salutation thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Despite share the same keywords, that's not a `for` loop; it's a list comprehension nested in *another* list comprehension. As such, you need to evaluate the inner list first:

```
[
  [int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, c + 1))) 
     for c in range(n_cols)
  ] 
    for r in range(n_rows)
]
```

If you were to "unroll" the inner one, it would look like

```
[
  [
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, 1))),
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, 2))),
    # ...
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(r + 1, n_cols-1))),
  ]
    for r in range(n_rows)
]
```

and further unrolling the outer one would result in

```
[
  [
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(1, 1))),
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(1, 2))),
    # ...
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(1, n_cols-1))),
  ],
  [
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(2, 1))),
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(2, 2))),
    # ...
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(2, n_cols-1))),
  ],
  # ...
  [
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(n_rows-1, 1))),
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(n_rows-1, 2))),
    # ...
    int(input("Enter value for {}. row and {}. column: ".format(n_rows-1, n_cols-1))),
  ]
]
```